# How to setup nginx to create a sub-domain?

Tags: nginx, web-hosting, nginx-config

I have one domain myartistbook.in, which is working fine. I want to create a sub-domain for it named adminpanel.myartistbook.in. The steps I followed are:

1. Added sub-domain name to /etc/hosts

```
     127.0.0.1 localhost
    ***.***.***.180 myartistbook
    ***.***.***.180 adminpanel.myartistbook
```

2. edited /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }
    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  myartistbook.in www.myartistbook.in;
        root         /root/krim.com;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

   server {
    listen 80;
    root /root/sites/adminpanel.com;
    server_name adminpanel.myartistbook.in www.adminpanel.myartistbook.in;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/;   
        }
    }
}
```

3. Added a file named adminpanel.com inside /etc/nginx/sites-available.

```
server {
          listen 80;
          server_name www.adminpanel.myartistbook.in;
          server_name ***.***.***.180;
          root /root/sites/adminpanel.com;
          index index.html;

          access_log /var/log/nginx/adminpanel.com.access.log;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/adminpanel.com.error.log;
          location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
          }
        }
```

4. Linked the above server block into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

> sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/adminpanel.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/adminpanel.com

5. Restarted nginx with

> sudo service nginx restart

While accessing the site I'm getting error ***adminpanel.myartistbook.in’s server IP address could not be found.***
Am I missing any step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with server-side configurations involving domains and subdomains in  `server_name`, you need to make sure that your DNS records for `myartistbook.in` are properly configured as well.

Have you added a DNS record to point `adminpanel.myartistbook.in` to your server? You can either add an A record or a CNAME record for this. Looking at a quick check using [whatsmydns.net for adminpanel.myartistbook.in](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/adminpanel.myartistbook.in), it seems you missed this step. Please check the documentation of your domain registrar on how to do this.

After adding the records, do a quick check again using whatsmydns.net if your CNAME/A record has taken effect.

In your step 3, modify the `server_name` to `adminpanel.myartistbook.in` without the `www`, unless this is actually your intention to use the whole www.adminpanel.myartistbook.in, which I don't think is the case here because you attempted to access it without the www:

> adminpanel.myartistbook.in’s server IP address could not be found.

Also, it's probably good  to use a different `server {}` block when referring to IP addresses as `server_name` then redirect to the domain/subdomain. However, redirecting from IP Address going to your domain/subdomain may be not be the priority now. Suggest to remove that line in the meantime.

Then run a quick `nginx -T` to check for errors in your configuration. If the check is successful, reload your nginx web server and try accessing the subdomain again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, you were right. Now I have added the A record. It is now visible here(https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/adminpanel.myartistbook.in) It seems it will take atleast 10 hrs to reflect the nginx changes. Will come back after it gets reflected.

Comment: Didn't actually get what u meant by this line: 'Also, it's probably good to use a different server {} block when referring to IP addresses as server_name then redirect to the domain/subdomain.'

Comment: Are you planning on making your site directly accessible using your IP address on purpose? This is potentially security issue when you start implementing HTTPS. If you don't apply redirection from IP address to domain, users can still access your site using HTTP via IP address even if you intended to have them use HTTPS only. So best practice to redirect them to https://myartistbook.in whenever they attempt to access using ***.***.***.180